# Bit flags - check if any of the specific flags (and no other) are set

Tags: bit-fields, bitmask

I'm using bit flags on player commands in-game to decide whether they should be allowed to execute or not.
So the list of bit flags is something like this:

```
CMD_NONE = 0x0,
CMD_TELEPORT = 0x1,
CMD_VIP = 0x2,
CMD_NO_LOG = 0x4, // don't log the execution of this command
```

And what I want to do is to make some func/macro to simplify things, because I want to check if let's say the command has set `CMD_TELEPORT` or `CMD_VIP` and **nothing** more, so both `CMD_TELEPORT` and `CMD_VIP` are optional and can be either on/off, but anything else cannot be enabled at the same time.

As for now I was checking this manually, but it's a pain in the ass.
I cannot use

```
if (flags == (CMD_TELEPORT | CMD_VIP)
```

because that checks if **both** of the flags are set at the same time, and I want them to be actually the only flags that **can** be set at all, but not neccessarily at the same time.
So it's either CMD_NONE, CMD_TELEPORT, CMD_VIP or (CMD_TELEPORT | CMD_VIP)

I could do some loop and check each of the flags if it's set and decrement it from the flag value and check if anything is remaining, but I'm hoping theres a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a point to `CMD_NO_LOG` if it shouldn't be usable?

Comment: It's just an example, I use more flags for different purposes but there are many cases when I want to only allow commands with specific flags, let's say the player is on some quest and I don't want to allow any teleportation or vip commands etc. so I just check for the `optional` flags that don't have any impact on the game itself (so it can be CMD_NONE, or CMD_NO_LOG but anything else is being blocked etc, there are also other optional flags)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check that no other bit than `CMD_TELEPORT` or `CMD_VIP` is set, you can mask them out and see if the result is non-zero:

```
if (flags & ~(CMD_TELEPORT|CMD_VIP)) {
    /* something else is set */
} else {
    /* just TELEPORT or VIP, or both, or nothing */
}
```

If you want to further check that only one of them is, you'll have to check that separately. With two flags, it's easy, but gets a bit repetitive with more of them.